# Why isn't the surjectivity of a covering map implied by its definition?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, covering-spaces

Although some authors require a covering map to be surjective by definition, I am, in particular, talking about the definition given by Hatcher:

> A **covering space** of a space $X$ is a space $\tilde X$ together with a map $p:\tilde X\to X$ satisfying the following condition: There exists an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $X$ such that for each $\alpha,\ p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is a disjoint union of open sets in $\tilde X$, each of which is mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U_\alpha$. *We do not require $p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ to be nonempty, so $p$ need not be surjective.*

I don't understand the remark made at the end. Since $\{U_\alpha\}$ covers $X$ and each member is the homeomorphic image of some open set in $\tilde X$, $p$ should be surjective. How come that it is possible that $p$ is not? Or did the author mean that $p$ only maps some part of $p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ onto $U_\alpha$ whenever $p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is nonempty?

What is an  example of a nonsurjective covering map?

Comment: The condition “is a disjoint union of open sets, each of which is mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U_{\alpha}$” is satisfied by the empty family. So if $p^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ is empty, then the condition is satified: every element of the empty set maps homeomorphically onto $U_{\alpha}$ via $p$.

Comment: For an example, consider a disjoint union of two circles for $X$, and one circle for $\overline{X}$, with $p$ mapping $\overline{X}$ to one of the circles in $X$ homeomorphically.  For open cover, take $U_1$ to be one circle, $U_2$ to be the other circle.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is it a convention that an empty set maps to homeomorphically onto another set? Naturally, one would think that an empty set and a nonempty set should not be homeomorphic.

Comment: No by definition of images etc. the empty set maps to the empty set. No convention, just set theory.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think I know where the problem is. Usually "onto" means "surjectively onto". But here "onto $U_\alpha$" means "onto its image inside $U_\alpha$". Am I right?

Comment: It seems to me Hatcher is including the possibility of an empty disjoint union of open sets, i.e. $\coprod_{\beta\in\emptyset}V_\beta$. Then each set in the collection $\lbrace V_\beta\mid\beta\in\emptyset\rbrace$ is mapped homeomorphically onto $U_\alpha$ (since there are in fact no sets in the collection).

Comment: @trisct No, I don't think that's the statement. It is as user17945 is noting: the empty *family* works as the family of preimages. Did you work out my example?